# Near real time update of dashboard in Python Streamlit

Tags: python, data-analysis, streamlit

I am new in python, and I have this personal project to produce dashboards using Streamlit. The code is running fine, shows bare bar graphs, but I want to make it update in near real time. The web app is connected to a google sheet, that when there's some changes in the google sheet, it should reflect in near real time. I saw something like 'Time' in youtube, but it doesn't seems to work with mine. Below is my code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Function to read data from the Google Sheet
def read_google_sheet(sheet_id, sheet_name):
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('keys.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet = client.open_by_key(sheet_id)
    data = sheet.worksheet(sheet_name).get_all_values()
    headers = data.pop(0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    return df

# Function to clean the data
def clean_data(df):
    df = df.dropna(subset=['Start Time', 'End Time'])  # Ignore rows with blank data in 'Start Time' or 'End Time' columns
    df['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Time'])
    df['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Time'])
    df = df[df['End Time'] > df['Start Time']]  # Ignore rows where 'End Time' is before 'Start Time'
    df = df[~df['Serial'].str.contains('END TIME')]  # Ignore 'END TIME' in 'Serial' column
    return df

# Load data from Google Sheet
sheet_id = "gsheet ID"
sheet_name = "Data"
data_df = read_google_sheet(sheet_id, sheet_name)

# Convert 'Date' column to datetime
data_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['Date'])

# Clean the data
data_df = clean_data(data_df)

# Create the Streamlit web app
st.title('Serials Processing Visualizations')

# Date selection with default value set to today's date
start_date = st.sidebar.date_input('Select Start Date', pd.Timestamp.today().date())
end_date = st.sidebar.date_input('Select End Date', pd.Timestamp.today().date())

# Convert 'start_date' and 'end_date' to datetime
start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date)
end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date)

# Filter data based on selected dates
filtered_data = data_df[(data_df['Date'] >= start_date) & (data_df['Date'] <= end_date)]

# Visualization 1: Total serials processed per employee
fig1 = px.bar(filtered_data.groupby('Employee')['Serial'].count().reset_index(),
              x='Employee', y='Serial', title='Total Serials Processed per Employee')
st.plotly_chart(fig1)

# Visualization 2: Total serials processed per task
fig2 = px.bar(filtered_data.groupby('Task')['Serial'].count().reset_index(),
              x='Task', y='Serial', title='Total Serials Processed per Task')
st.plotly_chart(fig2)

# Visualization 3: Total serials processed per task per employee
fig3 = px.bar(filtered_data.groupby(['Task', 'Employee'])['Serial'].count().reset_index(),
              x='Task', y='Serial', color='Employee',
              title='Total Serials Processed per Task per Employee')
st.plotly_chart(fig3)

# Visualization 4: Serials processed per hour per employee
filtered_data['Processing Hours'] = (filtered_data['End Time'] - filtered_data['Start Time']).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
fig4 = px.bar(filtered_data.groupby('Employee')['Processing Hours'].sum().reset_index(),
              x='Employee', y='Processing Hours', title='Serials Processed per Hour per Employee')
st.plotly_chart(fig4)

# Visualization 5: Serials processed per hour per task
fig5 = px.bar(filtered_data.groupby('Task')['Processing Hours'].sum().reset_index(),
              x='Task', y='Processing Hours', title='Serials Processed per Hour per Task')
st.plotly_chart(fig5)
```